# accessing global variables cost gas?

Tags: solidity

I assume reading global variables don't cost gas since it's not part of the contract, but I wanted to make sure in the future in case I have to optimize contracts for gas usage.

Comment: What do you mean with `global` functions? There is no such keyword in Solidity.

Comment: I mean to say msg.sender (address);, msg.value (uint); these special function. you don't need to declare it. It is globally available.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not functions but they are globally available variables (http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html).

As pointed out by @Ismael in the comments, calling them *does* cost gas when used in a transaction. Inside a (local) call they are free (but rather pointless - what would be the point of checking `msg.sender` locally?).

Comment: Actually they have a non zero cost in gas when used inside a transaction. From here https://github.com/djrtwo/evm-opcode-gas-costs for example `msg.sender` uses `CALLER` opcode cost 2 gas and `msg.value` uses `CALLVALUE` also costs 2 gas.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of variables in solidity language: state variables and local variables. State variables store on the Ethereum platform but local variables are not. Both consume the gas on the Ethereum platform. State variables declare within a smart contract and outside the functions. State variables consume more gas rather than local variables. Gas cost also depends upon on string and byte datatypes. string consumes more gas rather bytes that's why developers prefer to use bytes to develop the DApp application.

Answer (score 0):

Any read ie view functions didn't cost gas